# Pandas iterrows() too slow in Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, docker

I am iterating over a csv file stored in my docker. I want to iterate over the rows. The same script in my local(w/o docker) is done executing in 6 mins but when inside docker, reading 20 rows takes a min or two(there are 1.3M rows). The size of the csv file that is being read is 837MB

The code is as follows:

```
## added a script in the process just for test
import datetime
import sys

import pandas as pd

cleanup_consent_column = "rwJIedeRwS"
omc_master_header = [u'PPAC District Code', u'State Name', u'District Name', u'Distributor Code', u'OMC Name', u'Distributor Contact No', u'Distributor Name', u'Distributor Address', u'SO Name', u'SO Contact', u'SALES AREA CODE', u'Email', u'DNO Name', u'DNO Contact', u'Lat_Mixed', u'Long_Mixed']

#OMC_DISTRIBUTOR_MASTER = "/mnt/data/NFS/TeamData/Multiple/external/mopng/5Feb18_master_ujjwala_latlong_dist_dno_so_v7.csv"
#PPAC_MASTER = "/mnt/data/NFS/TeamData/Multiple/external/mopng/ppac_master_v3_mmi_enriched_with_sanity_check.csv"

def clean(input_filepath, OMC_DISTRIBUTOR_MASTER, PPAC_MASTER, output_filepath):
    print("Taylor Swift's clean.")
    df = pd.read_csv(input_filepath, encoding='utf-8', dtype=object)
    print ('length of input - {0} - num cols - {1}'.format(len(df), len(df.columns.tolist())))
    ## cleanup consent column
    for x in df.columns.tolist():
        if x.startswith("rwJIedeRwS"):
            del df[x]
            break
    ## strip ppac code from the baseline
    df['consumer_id_name_ppac_code'] = df['consumer_id_name_ppac_code'].str.strip()

    ## merge with entity to get entity_ids
    omc_distributor_master = pd.read_csv(OMC_DISTRIBUTOR_MASTER, dtype=object, usecols=omc_master_header)
    omc_distributor_master = omc_distributor_master.add_prefix("omc_dist_master_")
    df = pd.merge(
        df, omc_distributor_master, how='left',
        left_on=['consumer_id_name_distributor_code', 'consumer_id_name_omc_name'],
        right_on=['omc_dist_master_Distributor Code', 'omc_dist_master_OMC Name']
    )

    ## log if anything not found
    print ('responses without distributor enrichment - {0}'.format(len(df[df['omc_dist_master_Distributor Code'].isnull()])))
    print ('num distributors without enrichment - {0}'.format(
        len(pd.unique(df[df['omc_dist_master_Distributor Code'].isnull()]['consumer_id_name_distributor_code']))
    ))

    ## converting date column
    df['consumer_id_name_sv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['consumer_id_name_sv_date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    df['consumer_id_name_sv_date'] = df['consumer_id_name_sv_date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    ## add eventual_ppac_code
    print ("generating eventual ppac code column")
    count_de_rows = 0
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        count_de_rows += 1
        if count_de_rows % 10000 == 0:
            print(count_de_rows)
        ## if not found in master - use baseline data else go with omc master
        if row['omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code'] != row['omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code']:
            df.ix[i, 'eventual_ppac_code'] = row['consumer_id_name_ppac_code']
        else:
            df.ix[i, 'eventual_ppac_code'] = row['omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code']
    print(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
    print("I guess it's all alright!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("The main function has been called!")
    clean(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? have you profiled your code and found out which part exactly takes so much longer in your docker?

Comment: iterrows part is too slow.
Should I mount an additional space for docker to store and process large csv files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base premise of docker == ubuntu system is a logical fallacy that I was having. Yes, it is right to optimize code as much as possible but the same code within two systems showed different stats, docker being slow. Having said that, I started working with `chunksize` so as to reduce the memory burden. The context switch of (read and write) with such large data was what making docker slow(especially the write). It should be noted that memory was not the issue, writing large data in persistent storage via docker is slower than in our systems.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised regarding this. Dockers just provide a thin layer between itself and the Operating system. Speeds with the application running in docker should be identical to that running on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use loop your rows in the first place? This seems like it can be done vectorized:

```
df["eventual_ppac_code"] = df["omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code"]
df.loc[df["omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code"] != df["omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code"], "eventual_ppac_code"] = df["consumer_id_name_ppac_code"]
```

Having said that, when exactly do you expect `omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code` to **not** equal `omc_dist_master_PPAC District Code`? It's the exact same column?